# I am unable to print the result of the game with scores

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, loops, conditional-statements

This is my first project - **'Rock Paper Scissors'** game, it has two modes- single player and two players mode. when the game is played by two players, I am able to print the result and scores of the game successfully. But when the game is played by single player (with computer) I am unable to print the result with scores.

To print the result, I tried conditional statements. when the game is played by single player the **else** part of the conditional statements is getting printed always. The code is not checking the conditions of **if** part.

below is my code.

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1qNffzCM6xlSQOLV51EoGNbTIi_7agZ3T?usp=sharing

Comment: Don't make us click on an external link to see your code.  Post all code, output, and error messages directly in the question as plain text.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you are going to attach a link to your code, please also attach your code to the question. Links can be blocked by web filters, and can go offline. Attaching your code to the question removes both these issues. I recommend you check out [ask] and [edit] your question to add formatted code.

Answer (score 0):

You've made huge mistake making two different implementations for single and multiplayer modes. As well as is unclear why you have defined function 'win' inside loop. The short answer for your question is: you should to move function definition outside the loop and remain there only calls.
So, your loop should be somelike this:

```
   for i in range(0, 5):
        randno = random.randint(1,3)
        if randno == 1:
            comp = 'r'
        elif randno == 2:
            comp = 'p'
        elif randno == 3:
            comp = 's' 

        print('Computer is choosing')
        time.sleep(0.1)
        you = input("enter your choice:")
        print("computer choice was:",comp)
        a = win(comp,you)
```

But really you should to use the same `win()` function as for singleplayer as for multiplayer and the only difference should be sustain that one of parameters passed to `win()` will be inputed by user or generated by computer. Such approach gonna help you to minimize issues in future.
So, structure of your program in such case will be looking like this:

```
def win(p1, p2):
    ...

for i in range(0, 5):
    p1 = input(...)
    if no_of_players == 2:
        p2 = input(...)
    else:
        p2 = ['r', 'p', 's'][random.randint(0, 2)]
    win(p1, p2)
```